# Fill array value to specific keys in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, arraylist, functional-programming

I have array like below mentioned way,want to fill each array specific value to next repetitive keys till 7th number.

**INPUT:**

`Array
(
    [0] => 2015-02-07
    [1] => 2015-02-14
    [2] => 2015-02-21
)`

**Expected Output :**

Excepted output would be like

`Array
(
    [0] => 2015-02-07,
    [1] => 2015-02-07,
    [2] => 2015-02-07,
    [3] => 2015-02-07,
    [4] => 2015-02-07,
    [5] => 2015-02-07,
    [6] => 2015-02-07,
    [7] => 2015-02-14,
    [8] => 2015-02-14,
    [9] => 2015-02-14,
    [10] => 2015-02-14,
    [11] => 2015-02-14,
    [12] => 2015-02-14,
    [13] => 2015-02-14,
    [14] => 2015-02-21,
    [15] => 2015-02-21,
    [16] => 2015-02-21,
    [17] => 2015-02-21,
    [18] => 2015-02-21,
    [19] => 2015-02-21,
    [20] => 2015-02-21
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
<?php 

    $array =array('2015-02-07','2015-02-14','2015-02-21');
    $arr1='';
    foreach($array as $val)
    {
        for($i= 0; $i < 7; $i++)
        {
            $arr1[]=$val;
        }
    }
    echo "<pre>"; print_r($arr1);
?>
```

This will Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-02-07
    [1] => 2015-02-07
    [2] => 2015-02-07
    [3] => 2015-02-07
    [4] => 2015-02-07
    [5] => 2015-02-07
    [6] => 2015-02-07
    [7] => 2015-02-14
    [8] => 2015-02-14
    [9] => 2015-02-14
    [10] => 2015-02-14
    [11] => 2015-02-14
    [12] => 2015-02-14
    [13] => 2015-02-14
    [14] => 2015-02-21
    [15] => 2015-02-21
    [16] => 2015-02-21
    [17] => 2015-02-21
    [18] => 2015-02-21
    [19] => 2015-02-21
    [20] => 2015-02-21
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Skip all the `for ...`, `foreach ...`, `$i= ...`, `$i< ...`, `$i++`, `while ...` ceremony and start using functions.

Here's a functional way to do it using `array_reduce`, `array_merge`, and `array_fill`.

```
$xs = ['2015-02-07', '2015-02-14', '2015-02-21'];

$result = array_reduce($xs, function($ys, $x) {
    return array_merge($ys, array_fill(0, 7, $x));  
}, []);

print_r($result);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 2015-02-07
    [1] => 2015-02-07
    [2] => 2015-02-07
    [3] => 2015-02-07
    [4] => 2015-02-07
    [5] => 2015-02-07
    [6] => 2015-02-07
    [7] => 2015-02-14
    [8] => 2015-02-14
    [9] => 2015-02-14
    [10] => 2015-02-14
    [11] => 2015-02-14
    [12] => 2015-02-14
    [13] => 2015-02-14
    [14] => 2015-02-21
    [15] => 2015-02-21
    [16] => 2015-02-21
    [17] => 2015-02-21
    [18] => 2015-02-21
    [19] => 2015-02-21
    [20] => 2015-02-21
)
```

Comment: yes, Its very good alternative way without using Foreach and for loop.. Thanks naomik..

Comment: @Sundar you could try to forget that `foreach`, `for`, and `while` even exist. A+ Highly recommended.

Comment: Do you have experience in MYSQL Database.?we have using MYsql is back-end ,its running out of space.so how can we increase the disk space or any alternatives can do?

Comment: @Sundar comments are not the place to ask completely new questions. Just [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this :

```
$arrayDestination = array();
foreach($arraySource as $value) {
    for ($i=0 ; $i<7 ; $i++) {
       $arrayDestination[] = $value;
    }      
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can do something like this -

$arr = Array
(
    '0' => '2015-02-07',
    '1' => '2015-02-14',
    '2' => '2015-02-21'
);  //Input the array
$j = 0;
foreach($arr as $k=>$v) {
    $i = 0;
    while ($i < 7){
        $arr_final[$j] = $v;
        $i++;$j++;
    }
}
print_r ($arr_final); //display output
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$arrFirstArray = array(
'0'=>'2015-02-07',
'1'=>'2015-02-14',
'2'=>'2015-02-21',
);
$intFirstArray = count($arrFirstArray);

$arrSecondArray = array();

for($intI=0;$intI<$intFirstArray;$intI++)
{
for($intJ=0;$intJ<7;$intJ++){
    global $arrSecondArray;
    $arrSecondArray[]   = $arrFirstArray[$intI];
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arrSecondArray);
```

This will work.